# Google Action to play radio stream starts in the paused state on Google Home device

Tags: audio-streaming, playback, google-assistant

I am developing a simple Action to play an mp3 stream from a radio station using the example YAML code for media-obects in the Action Builder. There is no interaction after the user input "Hey Google, Talk to [radio station] and the conversation ends.

This works perfectly using Google assistant on phone but with a Google Home device, the command is understood and the Welcome text is spoken but then silence, UNTIL it is resumed either with the "Hey Google, Resume" command or via the touch panel. The device appears to start in the paused state. Has anyone experienced this and can anyone suggest a solution?

Out of interest, I surveyed a number of other Google Actions available in the Action Store which play radio station streams and many of them exhibit the same behaviour on the Google Home device, but some do work without having to Resume the stream, so it must be possible!

Answer (score 1):

So having asked the question the cause and the solution became apparent and was able to answer my own question. Credit goes to swenlink for the solution. In case anyone is faced with this problem, here is the slightly obscure resolution.
The Google documentation provides linked YAML code to implement streaming audio with Action Builder using media_objects and this code is widely used in Actions implemented for internet radio stations, many of which exhibit this problem.

https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/prompts-media

Implementing this leads to the problem described in the original post i.e. the stream does not play on Google smart speakers.
If, however, you remove the start_offset command, either by deleting the line or setting the time to 0s, then it works correctly on smart speaker devices (veriefied on Google Home and Nest devices).

I was unable to find any other reference to this issue so I hope it helps someone else.